# For loop works well on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why my code works well on Firefox and not on Chrome.

Basically what happens is that on Firefox the loop works and it prints the outputs on the page at every iteration and at the end.

On Chrome it only prints some of the outputs at the end of the loop.

I read that it might have to do with the way I'm asking the code to print the output on the page, which is .textContent, but I also tried to use .innerHtml and the problem persists.

The code is a bit long and I'm sure there is a shorter cleaner way to write, but it is my first project and this is the best I could do at this stage.
Thank you for your help :)

Here is what the html looks like:

```
const forma = document.querySelector('form');
const out0 = document.getElementById('user-choice');
const out1 = document.getElementById('computer-choice');
const out2 = document.getElementById('game-result');
const out3 = document.getElementById('user-score');
const out4 = document.getElementById('computer-score');
const out5 = document.getElementById('final-result');


        // get a ramdom choice between Rock-paper-scissor from Computer

        let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
        
        let randomValue  = function computerPlay() {

            let randomChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
            
            out1.textContent = randomChoice;

            return randomChoice;

        };

       

    function game() {

        let userScore = 0;
        let computerScore = 0;

        // iterate the function playRound 5 times with a for loop
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // prompt an initial message "Rock, paper, scissor" to ask the user to input one of the 3
        let sign = prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?");

        // use a function to compare the random choice from computer with what the user has input in the prompt and return a result
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
         
            
          if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {
            i = i -1;    
            return "It's a tie! Play again!";
                

         } else if (playerSelection  == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {
                
                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                // this is when the computer wins
                if(computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5; // so that it practically breaks out of the loop
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("   
                } else return "You lose this round! Paper beats rock.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {
                
                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if(userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Rock beats scissors.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {
                
                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if(userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Paper beats rock.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {
                i = i -1; 
                return "It's a tie! Play again!";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {
                
                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                if (computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("
                } else return "You lose this round! Scissors beat paper.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {
                
                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                if (computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("
                } else return "You lose this round! Rock beats scissors.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {
                
                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if(userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Scissors beat paper.";

            } else if (playerSelection  == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {
                i = i -1; 
                return "It's a tie! Play again!";
            // this currently doesn't work as it tries to convert the playerSelection toLowerCase, as requested in the let playerSelection = sign.toLowerCase(), but it cannot because the sign is null and so it returns an error that sign is null
            } else if(playerSelection === '' || playerSelection === null) {
                i = 0;
                 
            } else {
                i = i -1; 
                return "I think you forgot how to play this game!"; 
            }    


            }
            // store the playerSelection argument value (equal to user input made lower case) in a variable
            let playerSelection = sign.toLowerCase();
            // store the computerSelection argument value (equal to radom choice determined by function randomValue) in a variable
            let computerSelection = randomValue();

            // print the user input made to lower case in the paragraph tag
            out0.textContent = sign;
            // print the return statement from the function in the out2 tag
            out2.textContent= playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection); 

        }


        }

   // run the function
   game();
```

And this is my Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <div>
        <form>
            <strong>Your choice:</strong>
            <output type="text" id="user-choice"></output>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>  
        <form>
            <strong>Computer choice:</strong> 
            <output type="text" id="computer-choice"></output>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>  
        <form>
           <strong>Result of this round:</strong> 
            <output type="text" id="game-result"></output>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>  
        <form>
            <strong>User score:</strong> 
            <output type="number" id="user-score"></output>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>  
        <form>
            <strong>Computer score:</strong>
            <output type="number" id="computer-score"></output>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>  
        <form>
            <strong>Game result:</strong>
            <output type="text" id="final-result"></output>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to force the browser to render something. You will need to promisify it however, because requestAnimationFrame has a callback, and does not directly return a promise.

After doing that, your code should look like this:

```
const forma = document.querySelector('form');
const out0 = document.getElementById('user-choice');
const out1 = document.getElementById('computer-choice');
const out2 = document.getElementById('game-result');
const out3 = document.getElementById('user-score');
const out4 = document.getElementById('computer-score');
const out5 = document.getElementById('final-result');


// get a ramdom choice between Rock-paper-scissor from Computer

let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

let randomValue = function computerPlay() {
    let randomChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
    out1.textContent = randomChoice;
    return randomChoice;
};



async function game() {
    // iterate the function playRound 5 times with a for loop
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // prompt an initial message "Rock, paper, scissor" to ask the user to input one of the 3
        let sign = prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?");

        // use a function to compare the random choice from computer with what the user has input in the prompt and return a result
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
            if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {
                i = i - 1;
                return "It's a tie! Play again!";


            } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {

                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                // this is when the computer wins
                if (computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5; // so that it practically breaks out of the loop
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("
                } else return "You lose this round! Paper beats rock.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {

                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if (userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Rock beats scissors.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {

                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if (userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Paper beats rock.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {
                i = i - 1;
                return "It's a tie! Play again!";

            } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {

                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                if (computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("
                } else return "You lose this round! Scissors beat paper.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[0]) {

                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                out4.textContent = computerScore;
                if (computerScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Unfortunately you lost the game :("
                } else return "You lose this round! Rock beats scissors.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[1]) {

                userScore = userScore + 1;
                out3.textContent = userScore;
                if (userScore == 3) {
                    i = 5;
                    out5.textContent = "Congratulations, you won the game!"
                } else return "You win this round! Scissors beat paper.";

            } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == choices[2]) {
                i = i - 1;
                return "It's a tie! Play again!";
                // this currently doesn't work as it tries to convert the playerSelection toLowerCase, as requested in the let playerSelection = sign.toLowerCase(), but it cannot because the sign is null and so it returns an error that sign is null
            } else if (playerSelection === '' || playerSelection === null) {
                i = 0;

            } else {
                i = i - 1;
                return "I think you forgot how to play this game!";
            }
        }

        // store the playerSelection argument value (equal to user input made lower case) in a variable
        let playerSelection = sign.toLowerCase();
        // store the computerSelection argument value (equal to radom choice determined by function randomValue) in a variable
        let computerSelection = randomValue();

        // print the user input made to lower case in the paragraph tag
        out0.textContent = sign;
        // print the return statement from the function in the out2 tag
        out2.textContent = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);

        await promisifiedRequestAnimationFrame();
    }
}

function promisifiedRequestAnimationFrame() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {resolve()});
    })
}

// run the function
game();
```

**So what exactly changed?**

- We added a function, that returns a promise that resolves when the requestAnimationFrame is finished executing.
- We made game() asynchronous. This allows us to use "await"

**But why does it work?**

Well, alerts, prompts and confirms are supposed to halt the code until a user does something. Firefox does not allow direct spamming of them, so there is a small time frame between your prompts on FF, but Chrome doesn't really care about that. You want a lot of prompts? Fine! By using `window.requestAnimationFrame` combined with await we will force chrome to wait until a frame has been drawn.

Comment: Thank you very much @GoldenretriverYT for your prompt reply. I tried to do what you recommended but the problem didn't change. Now it does print some more outputs during the iterations and not just at the end... but not all of them and in a pretty random way.

Comment: Well, thats very weird... It works fine for me. You could try to force a "sleep" to give the browser more time to render instead. Instead of promisifiedRequestAnimationFrame(), we do promisifiedTimeout(ms) and inside the Promise we do setTimeout(() => {resolve()}, ms); ---- Here is a fiddle to see what the code would look like then: https://jsfiddle.net/Lx46e5ft/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to do that :)

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you very much for your help @GoldenretriverYT!!